# Unable to Open Android Studio

Tags: java, windows, android-studio

I have Windows 10 32 bit and I've installed Java, After installing Android Studio when I'm trying to open it, it's not opening, no prompt, no error message nothing. I've tried all methods available on the Internet include JAVA_HOME and all still in vain, Please help. It's windows 32bit so android studio is just a zip file, when I tried Android studio 1.5 which do comes with Installer, it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to uninstall Android Studio and try to reinstall it. 
Go to terminal "**Win + R and type cmd**" inside type *java -version*.

If it is installed, try to install Android again, else, just download java **jre** and java **jdk** and after install Android Studio.

However, you can try to go task admin and check if you have Android Studio running. Kill it if you have it started and after try to open Android Studio